# Why does SimpleQueue's put method freeze?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using the `SimpleQueue` class from `multiprocessing.queues`. My program was working fine until I had an abnormal termination. Now whenever I run it, it freezes at a `put` call, before any `get` calls are performed. My guess is that `SimpleQueue` uses a file or something similar as the underlying method of communication and it got corrupted.

Any ideas on how I can get `SimpleQueue` to work again? Preferably without restarting the computer, it's a shared machine with multiple people working on it at the same time.

Comment: This depends on whether you are on a Windows environment. The implementation of `SimpleQueue` relies on `Pipe`, which is platform dependent. On most platforms it just creates a `pipe(2)` or `socketpair(2)`, but on Windows it uses `win32.CreateNamedPipe`, which could suffer the observed behavior albeit it should be safe due to the use of `tempfile.mktemp`. Please include both your OS and your Python version.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 15 and python 2.7.1.

Question update: It's not the first `put` call, but it happens before any `get` calls are performed.

Comment: It's probably somehow connected to this CPython [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85722). Try to use [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `SimpleQueue.put()` seems to freeze when I make a lot of put calls, could that be the problem? (OS X, Anaconda, 2.7.10)

```
In [1]: from multiprocessing.queues import SimpleQueue
   ...: from time import time
   ...: 
   ...: def put_jobs(n):
   ...:     q = SimpleQueue()
   ...:     t0 = time()
   ...:     for i in xrange(n):
   ...:         q.put((i, (42, 0)))
   ...:     print '%.3f' % (time() - t0)
   ...: 

In [6]: put_jobs(1000)
0.004

In [7]: put_jobs(1000)
0.004

In [8]: put_jobs(2000)
0.007

In [9]: put_jobs(3000)
0.010

In [10]: put_jobs(4000)
```

(not returning for minutes)